# How to hide an image in JS having specific alt attribute content?

Tags: javascript, html, attr

I have a DOM as shown below in which I want to hide an image having specific alt attribute content.

All of them are inside the li tag with class `shows-grid__thumb`. The alt attribute contents are at **Line A (Vote 2015 Debates)**, **Line B (Vote 2015 Special)** and **Line C (Vote 2015 Phone-in)**.

```
<li class="shows-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
   <a class="shows-grid__img-link" href="" tabindex="0">
      <figure class="shows-grid__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
         <img src="" srcset="" alt="Vote 2015 Debates" data-fallback-img=""> <!-- Line A -->        
      </figure>
   </a>
</li>

<li class="shows-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
   <a class="shows-grid__img-link" href="" tabindex="0">
      <figure class="shows-grid__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
         <img src="" srcset="" alt="Vote 2015 Special" data-fallback-img=""> <!-- Line B -->        
      </figure>
   </a>
</li>

<li class="shows-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
   <a class="shows-grid__img-link" href="" tabindex="0">
      <figure class="shows-grid__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
         <img src="" srcset="" alt="Vote 2015 Phone-in" data-fallback-img=""> <!-- Line C -->   
      </figure>
   </a>
</li>

<li class="shows-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
   <a class="shows-grid__img-link" href="" tabindex="0">
      <figure class="shows-grid__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
         <img src="" srcset="" alt="Vote Reform" data-fallback-img="">      
      </figure>
   </a>
</li>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what JS code I need to add so that it hide images having alt attribute content `Vote 2015 Debates` , `Vote 2015 Special` and `Vote 2015 Phone-in` from the DOM/webpage. 
I don't want to hide that image which has alt attribute content `Voting Reform`.

This is what I have tried but more need to be done.

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll("li.shows-grid__thumb");

const ext = ["Vote 2015 Debates", "Vote 2015 Phone-in", "Vote 2015 Special"];

el.forEach(el =>

  el.setAttribute("style", "display: none;")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`img[alt='YOUR_STRING']`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll#Obtaining_a_list_of_matches) selector, following snippet give the desire result on clicking the button:

```js
const ext = ["Vote 2015 Debates", "Vote 2015 Phone-in", "Vote 2015 Special"];

ext.forEach(el =>
  document.querySelector("img[alt='" + el + "']").closest('li').setAttribute("style", "display: none;")
);
```

```html
<li class="shows-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
  <a class="shows-grid__img-link" href="" tabindex="0">
    <figure class="shows-grid__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <img src="" srcset="" alt="Vote 2015 Debates" data-fallback-img="">
      <!-- Line A -->
    </figure>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="shows-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
  <a class="shows-grid__img-link" href="" tabindex="0">
    <figure class="shows-grid__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <img src="" srcset="" alt="Vote 2015 Special" data-fallback-img="">
      <!-- Line B -->
    </figure>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="shows-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
  <a class="shows-grid__img-link" href="" tabindex="0">
    <figure class="shows-grid__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <img src="" srcset="" alt="Vote 2015 Phone-in" data-fallback-img="">
      <!-- Line C -->
    </figure>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="shows-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
  <a class="shows-grid__img-link" href="" tabindex="0">
    <figure class="shows-grid__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <img src="" srcset="" alt="Vote Reform" data-fallback-img="">
    </figure>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I don’t want that on clicking the button. I want it on page load.

Comment: Its looking good. I am wondering if I can apply `display:none` on `li tag` because in that way it doesn't create blank space on the page. The rest of the items from the bottom will cover the blank space.

Comment: Applying `display:none` on img tag is generating blank space and not pushing any items from **bottom to top**.

Comment: @flash I've added [`closest('li')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) fro the image selector, please have a look at the updated snippet